# Unable send message continuity via socket

Tags: php, python, sockets

I'm trying to make a communication system between python server and php client. Php client will connect to python server and send a message and close to make completely. But when I connect and send message again, python server can't receive this message while in opening then client can't get `you are client111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` line, but when I telnet on commandline to connect to server then everything work well. Please help! Sorry my bad english.

Here is my code.

**python server**

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall('you are client111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

**php client**

**socket.php**

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 10000, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "You message");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Update question : Message sent via ajax when press a button event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function buttonPress() {

                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'post',
                        url : 'socket.php',
                        success : function(mess){

                        }
                    });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there any error message if you visit your socket.php directly?

Comment: @KoalaYeung: No, I just only send message to server one-shot, can't send again. I checked on chrome develop tool, no response from socket.php request `pending` status.

Comment: You can try to change the host parameter in your socket.php from 127.0.0.1 to localhost. If you run socket.php from browser or command line, what error does it display ?